# Widget for controlling tethering

Tags: tethering, app-widgets, usb-tethering

Are there any widgets on the market that let me control standard Android tethering? I use it quite a lot and it's a pain to have to navigate through all the Settings options just to check a checkbox...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply install the [GoLauncherEX](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5nYXUuZ28ubGF1bmNoZXJleCJd) and then install the [GO Switch Widget](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.gau.go.launcherex.gowidget.switchwidget&feature=more_from_developer#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwMiwiY29tLmdhdS5nby5sYXVuY2hlcmV4Lmdvd2lkZ2V0LnN3aXRjaHdpZGdldCJd). It is awesome and lets you control lot of other functionality other than tethering.

Comment: 'GO Switch Widget' does not have any option for controlling tethering.

Comment: It does have a widget for Wifi AP.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Tethering Widget](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.achmyr.android.froyo&hl=en). 
Its a free widget with nice look.
It can be used to enable/disable WiFi and USB Tethering as well.

To add, press Home button

```
Menu | Add | Widget | Tethering (full) / Tethering (small)
```